# mysql right join with group by problem

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have 2 tables:

1. ***LandingPages*** - contain landing pages per campaign.
2. ***Reports*** - contain hits and conversion per landing page.

I try to do query that bring the sum of hits and conversion per landing page,

But i want that if the landing page has not received any hits and conversion (***and not show in reports table***) then i want that return 0 as result.

What i do until now is:

```
SELECT l.LandingPageId, SUM(Hits) AS Hits, SUM(PixelSum) AS Conversion 
FROM Report c
RIGHT JOIN LandingPages l ON(c.LandingPageId = l.LandingPageId )
WHERE c.CampaignId = x  
AND DayDate > 'y'
GROUP BY c.LandingPageId
```

The problem is that i get only rows with the landing page that exist in reports table and pass the date 'y',

(e.g : i get only 2 rows of landing page , but there is 4 landing page

if i run this query i get 4 results

```
SELECT l.LandingPageId FROM LandingPages l WHERE l.CampaignId = x
```

)

not the all landing page (with 0 value),

how can i get this to work like i want, give me also the landing page that not in report table or in the table but in old date   ?

thanks.

## update :

I was helped a lot for your answers,  I got partial solution that work for me only if the landing page not exist at all in report table, but if it is exist but the date clause not match it not appear  :

the partial solution query :

```
 SELECT l.LandingPageId, IFNULL(SUM(Hits),0) AS Hits, IFNULL(SUM(PixelSum),0)  AS Conversion
    FROM LandingPages l
    LEFT JOIN Report c  ON( l.LandingPageId = c.LandingPageId) 
    WHERE (l.CampaignId = x OR  l.CampaignId IS NULL) 
    AND (DayDate > 'y' OR DayDate IS NULL)
    GROUP BY l.LandingPageId
```

**I still need your help !**

thanks!

Comment: Can you show the content of the two tables for a certain campaign. How many rows do you get if you do not do a GROUP BY? You should get 4. Remember that you make sums.

Comment: the report table contain thousands of lines per campaign because that i dont bring this

Comment: if Jürgen Hollfelder table creation is correct could you please print out what you would expect the results table to deliver? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i take the idea of thomas ,
 and with little improve its work !

the query :

```
Select L.LandingPageId
    , Coalesce( Sum( R.Hits ), 0 ) As Hits
    , Coalesce( Sum( R.PixelSum ), 0 ) As Conversion
From LandingPages As L
    Left Join Report As R
        On R.LandingPageId = L.LandingPageId
            And L.CampaignId = X
            And R.DayDate > 'y' 
WHERE L.CampaignId = X
Group By L.LandingPageId
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay. When I run the following I get the result from below. Is that what you want?

```
drop table landingpages;
create table landingpages (campaignid number, landingpageid number,  daydate number);

insert into landingpages values (1,100,20);
insert into landingpages values (1,101,21);
insert into landingpages values (2,102,20);
insert into landingpages values (2,103,21);

drop table report;
create table report (campaignid number, landingpageid number, hits number, pixelsum number);

insert into report values (1,100, 2, 1 );
insert into report values (2,102, 20, 21 );
insert into report values (2,103, 30, 31 );

commit;

SELECT c.LandingPageId, SUM(Hits) AS Hits, SUM(PixelSum) AS Conversion  
    FROM landingpages c 
    LEFT JOIN report l ON(c.LandingPageId = l.LandingPageId ) 
    WHERE c.CampaignId = 1   
    AND DayDate > 19 
    GROUP BY c.LandingPageId 


LANDINGPAGEID       HITS CONVERSION
------------- ---------- ----------
          100          2          1
          101                      


2 rows selected.
```

I hope this is what you need. I ran the above on Oracle but it should be no real difference in mySQL as this is all standard query language.

Comment: @haim evgi - He was close, you need to select from LandingPages FIRST since you want all records from that table, then left join report in order to get matched records from that table.

Comment: Can you add a reference like Also see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for a short explanation of the join types ? It's not really worth a full answer :)

Comment: Agree. The link would be good. I wanted to add one. I had only the link to German site. So thanks for your help.

Comment: +1 I appreciate what you did, but in mysql is dont work for me i dont know why, its strange

Answer (score 2):

First, you did not tell us in which table `Hits`, `PixelSum`, or `DayDate` are stored. The `?` represents that fact in my query. Obviously, the `?` will need to replaced with the proper alias. However, I assumed that `DayDate` came from the Report table given that you later mentioned a problem if the date criteria did not match.

In short, you need to apply that criteria in the ON clause of the Left Join. The ON clause criteria is applied *before* it is joined to the LandingPages table. Thus, Campaigns <> X will be filtered out in addition to `DayDate` values <= 'y' (Btw, what is the data type of `DayDate`? `DayDate > 'y'` looks suspicious to me) before the Report table is then joined to the LandingPages table.

In addition, you should consider using `Coalesce` instead of `IsNull` since `Coalesce` is the ISO standard.

```
Select L.LandingPageId
    , Coalesce( Sum( ?.Hits ), 0 ) As Hits
    , Coalesce( Sum( ?.PixelSum ), 0 ) As Conversion
From LandingPages As L
    Left Join Report As R
        On R.LandingPageId = L.LandingPageId
            And R.CampaignId = X
            And ( R.DayDate > 'y' Or R.DayDate Is Null )
Group By L.LandingPageId
```

[For more information on Left Joins, here is a visual representation](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's b/c of the RIGHT JOIN.  Rerun it as:

```
SELECT l.LandingPageId, SUM(Hits) AS Hits, SUM(PixelSum) AS Conversion 
FROM LandingPages l
LEFT JOIN Reports c ON(c.LandingPageId = l.LandingPageId )
WHERE c.CampaignId = x  
AND DayDate > 'y'
GROUP BY c.LandingPageId
```

Comment: i get only 2 rows of landing page , but there is 4 landing page

Comment: If you run with the join remarked out do you get all 4 records?  Please note that I reversed order of the tables as well, not just made it a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: how remark out the join ? if i do this SELECT l.LandingPageId  FROM 
LandingPages l 
WHERE l.CampaignId = x  i get 4 results

Comment: You need to throw in the date as well since you are using that in your WHERE clause.  Also are you sure your GROUPING isn't reducing  your result set?

Comment: what you mean throw the date ? the date is in report table , and i need it to show only records that pass this date

Comment: Sorry, you didn't include a schema!  Go read the page on JOIN in the comments on the other answer.  This should be very easy to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have this: `WHERE c.CampaignId = x` this means that if the landing page has not received any hits and conversion (and not show in reports table), the landing page will never show up in the results, although you use right join. Your c.CampaignId would be null for those landing pages and c.CampaignId = x would be false.

try:

```
SELECT l.LandingPageId, SUM(Hits) AS Hits, SUM(PixelSum) AS Conversion 
FROM Report c
RIGHT JOIN LandingPages l ON(c.LandingPageId = l.LandingPageId )
WHERE (c.CampaignId = x  or c.CampaignId is null)  
AND DayDate > 'y'
GROUP BY l.LandingPageId
```

I also group by l.LandingPageId because for landing pages with no reports, c.LandingPageId is null.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems I see...

- please prefix your columns (i.e., l.fieldname, c.fieldname) in all cases, so I can tell which table you're getting them from.  Anyway, I made some sample code for you below, but am not sure about it 100% since i didn't always know the table, which is important with a RIGHT JOIN, so you may need to adjust it.
- when you set criteria (WHERE c.CampaignID = something) on a right-joined table, you are turning it into an INNER JOIN.  If you want to avoid this, then add "...or c.CampaignID is null).  Because the idea of the RIGHT join is, *IF* there's a campaignID, you want it to be 'x', but If there's no campaign, that's ok too.  (right?)

you can't sum nulls, so i added coalesce to change nulls to zero.

```
SELECT 
   l.LandingPageId, 
   SUM(COALESCE(Hits,0)) AS Hits, 
   SUM(PixelSum) AS Conversion 
FROM 
      Report c
   RIGHT JOIN 
      LandingPages l 
   ON
      (c.LandingPageId = l.LandingPageId )
WHERE c.CampaignId = x OR c.CampaignID is null 
AND DayDate > 'y'
GROUP BY c.LandingPageId
```